# Install Bootstrap on Windows: npm update check failed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm

When I run `npm run dist` to install Boostrap, I'm getting `npm update check failed` error on Windows. How should I fix this? I'm using git bash, so there is no `sudo` command.

```
> bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 js-minify-bundle C:\webui\bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2\bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2
> uglifyjs --compress typeofs=false --mangle --comments "/^!/" --source-map "content=dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js.map,includeSources,url=bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map" --output dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js

INFO: Using input source map: dist/js/bootstrap.js.map
INFO: Using input source map: dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js.map

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                   npm update check failed                    │
│             Try running with sudo or get access              │
│             to the local update config store via             │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\Jack Yu\.config │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

> bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 js-minify-standalone C:\webui\bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2\bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2
> uglifyjs --compress typeofs=false --mangle --comments "/^!/" --source-map "content=dist/js/bootstrap.js.map,includeSources,url=bootstrap.min.js.map" --output dist/js/bootstrap.min.js dist/js/bootstrap.js

INFO: Using input source map: dist/js/bootstrap.js.map

> bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 js-minify-bundle C:\webui\bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2\bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2
> uglifyjs --compress typeofs=false --mangle --comments "/^!/" --source-map "content=dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js.map,includeSources,url=bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map" --output dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js

INFO: Using input source map: dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js.map

> bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 js-minify-docs C:\webui\bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2\bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2
> uglifyjs --mangle --comments "/^!/" --output assets/js/docs.min.js assets/js/vendor/anchor.min.js assets/js/vendor/clipboard.min.js assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js assets/js/src/application.js assets/js/src/pwa.js


┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                   npm update check failed                    │
│             Try running with sudo or get access              │
│             to the local update config store via             │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\Jack Yu\.config │
```

Comment: sudo in Windows is roughly equivalent to being logged in with admin permissions. Do you have admin permissions when you run the installation?

Comment: When I run as Administrator, I'm still getting the same problem.